# Deploy release tag Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a release pipeline in Azure DevOps where I copy files from the remote repository to a target location on a server.
[image: Release Pipeline]

In the application I am deploying I would like to display the version number of the application as the tag number for which the application was deployed, as for instance v1.41.

[image]

[image]

Since every release is linked to a commit, which is linked to a tag in my workflow, I am wondering if there is a way to "push" the tag name associated to the release onto the server, as for instance, to write a file with the tag number? Perhaps there are better solutions than this, I am a newb in Azure DevOps :P